# How to determine where defined Ruby object?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code in two files:

create_object.rb

```
def create_object
  method = 'new'
  Object.send(method)
end
```

debug.rb

```
require_relative './create_object'

def foo
  object = create_object
  bar(object)
end

def bar(object)
  # history_of_life - some method that returns object info
  puts object.history_of_life
end

foo
```

Run `ruby debug.rb`. I expect `history_of_life` method returns something like this:

`<Object:0x007f874b083430> initialized in create_object.rb:3`

Are there tools like `pry-stacktrace` to determine the place in the code where the Object was initialized?

Comment: You could override `create_object` and print its `caller`.

Answer (score 1):

It’s obviously off by default due to enormous footprint, but one might achieve more-or-less desired behaviour with [`ObjectSpace#allocation_class_path`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-allocation_class_path).

In general, `ObjectSpace` tweaks are your friends in tasks like this one on the top ([ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)) abstraction level.

Comment: Also, undocumented `RubyVM::InstructionSequence` might be a good source of inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectSpace.allocation_sourcefile` returns the source file origin from the given object. Thanks for [Aleksei Matiushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61453592/2109121) advice.

debug.rb

```
require 'objspace'
require_relative './create_object'

def foo
  object = create_object
  bar(object)
end

def bar(object)
  puts ObjectSpace.allocation_sourcefile(object)
end

ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations do
  foo
end
```

output

```
/home/user/pro/test/create_object.rb
```